# Need better formula for copying select data from a column and pasting to a new column with np blank cells in between

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get better formula to copy select data from column d and paste to column g with no empty cells my current formula works, but leaves blank cells like original column.

Current formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(ArrayFormula(mod(row(D3:D28),4))=3,D3:D28,))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample sheet with the given values on the screenshot for us to better replicate the issue? Manually typing all values would consume a lot of time and effort and providing a sample sheet would be efficient for the community to work on.

Comment: also, would `=filter(D:D, D:D > 0)` work on your case?

Comment: Posted this as an answer. Let me know if there are any changes or any specifics I missed out.

Answer (score 1):

or query:

```
=QUERY(D:D; "where D is not null"; )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

How about using `=filter` instead of `=arrayformula`.

```
=filter(D:D, D:D <> "")
```

or

```
=filter(D:D, D:D > 0)
```